# Unable to upload files with cURL and CreateProcess (tiny-process-library)

Tags: c++, windows, curl, unicode, createprocess

I am using the [tiny-process-library](https://gitlab.com/eidheim/tiny-process-library) to execute cURL commands, which uses CreateProcess under the hood on Windows. I have trouble uploading files on Windows but not on macOS. When trying to upload a file with japanese characters in the name I always run into the error callback with the cURL-warning

```
curl: Can't open 'C:/Users/bob/AppData/Local/Temp/?.mp3'!
```

Now I am wondering if this is an issue with my cURL command or if it is a problem how I am using the library. With other filenames this is working fine.

Example code:

```
#include "process.hpp"
#include <codecvt>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> converter;

int main() 
{
    std::string command(u8"curl \"https://api.example.com/media/test.mp3?format=json\" -T \"C:/Users/bob/AppData/Local/Temp/ぁ.mp3\"");

    std::wstring cmd = converter.from_bytes(command);
    std::wstring path;

    auto outCb = [&](const char* bytes, size_t n) {
        std::cout << std::string(bytes, n);
    };
    auto errCb = [&](const char* bytes, size_t n) {
        std::cout << std::string(bytes, n);
    };

    TinyProcessLib::Config cfg;
    cfg.buffer_size = 64;

    TinyProcessLib::Process process(cmd, path, outCb, errCb, false, cfg);
}
```

Comment: Side note: Why not just use libcurl directly? This seems oddly complicated

Comment: You are converting a UTF-8 `std::string` to a UTF-16 `std::wstring`, why not just start with `std::wstring` to begin with? Either way, it is clear that when the command reaches `CreateProcess()`, it is likely being converted to ANSI instead of using the original Unicode (ie, sounds like TinyProcess is using `CreateProcessA()` and not `CreateProcessW()`). All the more reason to use [libcurl](https://curl.se/libcurl/) instead of shelling out to `curl.exe`

Comment: The code above is just a minimal example to show the problem. This concept is used in a bigger cross-platform (therefore the conversion from utf8) system, so just changing to libcurl is not an option right now. TinyProcess is using the CreateProcess macro which then depends on the project settings but I am rather sure that it should take CreateProcessW in my example project.

Comment: If that were true, you would not be be seeing the filename `ぁ.mp3` converted to `?.mp3`, unless `curl.exe` itself is doing a Unicode->ANSI conversion internally, in which case you are SOL. Either way, all the more reason to use libcurl (which is cross-platform). Also see [curlpp](http://www.curlpp.org/).

Comment: The translation to `?.mp3` could be a limitation of windows console printing, it might not have the font for example. Does this work if you call `curl` directly through `CreateProccess`? Also `curl` has option for `charset = UTF8` you could try.